# Bash output tracking

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I made an infinite loop in the Bash script to restart streaming.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
  do
    ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://{address:port}/{key}" -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -c:a libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -c:v copy -threads 2 -bufsize 512k -f flv "rtmps://{address:port}/live/{key}" &
    PID=$!
    sleep 12h
    kill $PID
    sleep 2
 done
```

But sometimes an error occurs... which is displayed in the console in the following form:

```
rtsp://{address:port}/{key}: Invalid date found when processing input
```

And this time the stream does not work. How to supplement my script, which would track after running the command output in the console and when the error **Invalid date found when processing input** will end the process and immediately restart the stream?

Answer (score 1):

If ffmpeg wasn't launched in the background this would be a lot easier: you'd just have to check the exit status.

But because we're dealing with multiple processes, we'll have to incorporate some inter-process communication.

Using signals: this is **untested**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# set up a signal handler for SIGUSR1
trap 'echo "ffmpeg died!"; exit 1' USR1

while true; do
    (   # start a subshell
        # if ffmpeg exits non-zero, signal the parent shell
        ffmpeg -options... || kill -s USR1 $$
    ) &
    # rest of loop is the same
done
```